# rsync on fat32 and ntfs

Tags: filesystems, rsync, fat32

A little background:  I have tried to use rsync to backup my wife's home directory to an external usb drive with the command

```
rsync -va /home/wife /run/media/wife
```

but kept getting error messages that mkstemp failed, and that rsync failed to set times, becuase of a read-only filesystem.  Worse, it seems that rsync is unable to tell when files don't need syncing, and winds up copying a lot of stuff it doesn't need to, resulting in rediculously slow backup times.

So I tried using `rsync -rtvO` instead, based on [this guy's advice](http://www.andrewboring.com/technotes/rsync-fat32-drives).  Okay, no more warnings, but the backups still seem too slow, and esp on big media files that already exists -- i.e. it's still copying stuff unnecessarily.

1. Is my analysis correct?
2. Is there a workaround?
3. Will the problem be fixed if I use an NTFS drive for here backups?

I could of course use a linux filesytem, but on rare occasions she would like to be able to take the drive to work and access it from the Windows machines there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Try using `--modify-window=1`

   > In particular, when transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT
   >   filesystem (which represents times with a 2-second resolution),
   >   --modify-window=1 is useful (allowing times to differ by up to 1 second).

   https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html
2. You could also try using `--size-only`

   > skip files that match in size

For rsync to FAT, this is what I use and it seems to work pretty well:

```
rsync -rtv --modify-window=1 source/ destination/
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/144475/58568